# How to troubleshoot Windows computer that occasionally loses Wi-Fi (WiFi) network connectivity for ~60 seconds

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

A friend reached out for me to help with their Windows 7 computer that is occasionally losing Wi-Fi (WiFi) network connectivity.  Each time it loses Wi-Fi connectivity (reportedly about once per day), it magically starts working again after about 60-90 seconds (without user interaction). One of the biggest challenges is that the issue is sporadic, and they have no way to reproduce it on-demand.

This is reportedly a new issue, although none of their networking or computer hardware has changed.  Other Wi-Fi devices on their network do not experience this issue.  They do not have Ethernet devices on their network.

I was thinking this may be a DHCP issue, as they experienced some connectivity issues when they installed an IoT Wi-Fi thermostat.  On the other hand, DHCP leases are typically at least 24 hours, and they turn off their computer completely off at least once every day.

Here's what I've had them do so far:

1. Scan for malware on all devices
2. Remove all devices from router's history
3. Reboot modem and router
4. Reboot computer
5. Verify a strong Wi-Fi signal at the location of the computer
6. Verify the Wi-Fi channel being used is not over-congested
7. Look in the Windows event logs for related errors
8. Use a different DNS
9. Ensure no microwave devices are running
10. Verify no other devices on the network are transmitting/receiving substantial traffic when this issue occurs
11. Verify all drivers are up-to-date
12. Verify modem and router are using the latest firmware

So far, none of these actions has resulted in improvement.

I'm leaning towards a router, firewall, or Windows configuration issue, but there are many places to look.  I want to continue to help, but I'm busy with many tasks, so I prefer to not spend too many hours figuring this out for them.  I am happy to spend another 1-2 hours on this task for them.

I'm writing with the hope that one or more Super User community members can post additional important items to check, or additional tasks to perform.

Comment: One easy thing to check is try turning off bluetooth, especially if the wifi device is a bluetooth/wifif/ethernet combo. See if it resolves.

Comment: @Yorik Thank you for the tip. Curious... why does that sometimes help?  I asked about Bluetooth, and the response I received was: *"Bluetooth is always turned off, but Bluetooth drivers do get loaded when system boots"*.  Is that sufficient?

Comment: bluetooth radio interference can disrupt wifi. So if it is *off* or *disabled* (as opposed to simply not connected to other devices), then you have eliminated bluetooth interference from the same chipset as a cause. My wife has had several laptops with realtek combo chips where bluetooth radio would trash her wifi

Comment: My wife's laptop had a similar issue. Went through most of the same steps you have, then tried turning off the built in wifi card and running through a USB wifi device.  No more disconnects.  Had already done several remove/reinstalls of the card drivers, so it appeared that hers was something physical with the card (bad solder that disconnects when it reaches a certain temp, maybe?).  Anyway, if you have a USB wifi device, you might try the same to see if it is a physical card problem.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Yorik: Disable bluetooth devices.

Also

Firstly, CREATE A RESTORE POINT:

• Click Start ( ), right-click Computer, and then select Properties.
• On the left side of the System window, click System protection. ...
• Select a disk to store the restore point system files from the list, usually (C:), and then click Create.

---

Change Power Plan

Go to start, open Control Panel then open Power Options; now you have to click onChange plan settings right in front of "Balanced (recommended)" - below " Plans shown on the battery meter -  after that click on Change advanced power settings now all you need is to find (Wireless Adapter Settings => Power Saving Mode => On battery) and change On battery to Maximum Performance.

---

Try these four (4) fixes, listed here: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/laptop-keeps-disconnecting-from-wifi-fixed/#d

• Restart your computer and network devices

• Disable your network adapter power saving setting

• Update your network driver (stated above)

• Change Scan Valid Interval

OR SOLUTION 3 https://fixkb.com/2011/04/wireless-problems-without-charger.html

(Read the comments section (scroll down), Many say Solution 1 worked - Change Power Plan- described above)

• Click the Start Button.

• Type “Device Manager” and press Enter.

• Click Continue if prompted.

• Click the [+] next to Network adapters.

• Right Click on “Realtek RTL8191SE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC” or similar Wireless card.

• Click Properties.

• Click on the Advanced Tab.

• Click on 802.11d.

• On the right hand side change the drop down to Enabled.

• The  following steps are optional but may help:

• Select TX power level.

• On the right hand side change the drop down to 100%.

• Select Wireless mode.

• On the right hand side change the drop down menu to “IEEE 802.11b/g”.

• If you regularly stream music to other computer in your house do not change these options. Although 802.11b/g are more stable protocols, the maximum speed is 54Mbps.

• Click OK.